# Injected messages returning null in eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my plugin, I have created separate packages for maintaining the messages.properties.In that same package I have created my Mesages.java class as well. Following is my message class

```java
   @Message(contributionURI="platform:/plugin/com.chinna.test.properties.messages")
public class Messages {
    public String test1;
    public String test2;
}
```

Then injected the message in a different package of the same plugin. like follows. The class in which injected is singleton class.

```java
    @Inject
    @Translation
    Messages messages;
```

after I injected it I tried access messages.properties in the code like follows

```java
messages.test1
```

But my application is throwing Null-Pointer exception. since the "messages" is null.

even though I injected, I do not know why "messages" is null.

Could any please help me?

Comment: Is the class where you are trying to use the messages actually injected (either a class referenced in the Application.e4xmi or created with ContextInjectionFactory)? You are also telling the system to load the messages from a plugin called `com.chinna.test.properties.messages` - is that correct?

Comment: @greg-449 no this class is not referred to in the Application.e4xmi nor created via ContextInjectionFactory. this class just a singleton object used in a part.

Comment: Then it is not injected and this can't be used - see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use this in classes which are injected.

Injection is only done on classes referenced in the Application.e4xmi, some extension points or created/injected using the `ContextInjectionFactory` `make` or `inject` methods.

For other classes the older style of messages file extending `NLS` and calling `NLS.initializeMessages` can be used.